# Compare version number strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

"The following is the link to the problem I'm trying.

https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/compare-version-numbers/

I simulated the array to compare both the versions. But I couldn't find any mistake in the code."

```
 int compareVersion(string A, string B) {
```

// vnum1, vnum2  store each numeric part of version A and B

```
      long long int vnum1 = 0, vnum2 = 0;
```

//  loop until both strings are processed

```
    //  storing numeric part of version A in vnum1 
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(i<A.length()||j<B.length()){


    while (i < A.length()&&A[i]!='.') 
    {    
        vnum1 = vnum1 * 10 + (A[i]-'0'); 
        i++; 
    } 

    //  storing numeric part of version B in vnum2 
    while (j < B.length()&&B[j]!='.') 
    { 
        vnum2 = vnum2 * 10 + (B[j] - '0'); 
        j++; 
    } 

    if (vnum1 > vnum2) 
        return 1; 
   else  if (vnum2 > vnum1) 
        return -1; 

    //  if equal, reset variables and go for next numeric 

    vnum1=0;
    vnum2=0;
    i++;
    j++;

   }  return 0; 
   }
```

**Input**

```
A="444444444444444444444444"
B="4444444444444444444444444"
```

**Actual**:

```
 1
```

**Expected**:

```
-1
```

Comment: I did the same but with given input its not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the version numbers as dot-separated strings. Get the first one from each input string and compare. If they are not equal you can return with the result immediately, otherwise you get the next dot-separated number, and so on until you reach the end of the string.

[`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) could help you.

---

If the version numbers could be of arbitrary length, the you can still treat it as a dot-separated input and use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline` to extract the numbers into strings. But then instead of converting them to integers that you can compare you need to check character by character.

First strip leading zeroes from the strings (so e.g. `"01"` becomes `"1"`). Then compare the length of the string. The longer string will always be larger.

Once you've past that stage, get the least significant digit (the last character in the strings) and do a simple character comparison (the C++ specification have wording that says that the character `'1'` will always be smaller than the character `'2'`). As long as the characters are equal you iterate backwards over the strings, comparing character by character.